# Update data for custom object through Apex class and visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, data, update

I created a Custom object Customer. First I want to show the details of a particular record on a page and then update that record after clicking on command button on the same page but my values are not going to be update.It is taking the old values.
My visual force code is as below :

```
<apex:page controller="EditCustomerData1" showHeader="false">
    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="block" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!customerDetails}" var="cust" style="width:100%">
                    <apex:column style="width:100%" headerValue="Customer Information">
                        <br/>
                        Customer Name &nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:inputText style="width:100px" label="Cust" value="{!cust.name}"/><br/><br/>
                        Email Id      &nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:InputField label="Email" value="{!cust.Email__c}"/><br/> <br/>
                        Active       &nbsp;&nbsp;    <apex:inputField label="Active" value="{!cust.APEX_Active__c}"/><br/><br/>
                        Country &nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:inputfield value="{!cust.Country__c}"/><br/><br/>                       
                        City &nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:inputfield value="{!cust.City__c}"/><br/><br/>                        
                        <!--<apex:commandLink action="{!SaveData}" value="Edit">
                              <Apex:param value="{!cust.name}" name="CustomerName"/>
                        </apex:commandLink><br/>-->
                        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!SaveData}" reRender="block" >
                            <Apex:param value="{!cust.name}" name="CustomerName"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:column>                                       
                </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My apex class is as below :

```
public class EditCustomerData1 {
    string customerId{get;set;}
    public List<APEX_Customer__c> customerDetails{get;set;}
    public List<APEX_Customer__c> updateCustomer{get;set;}

    public EditCustomerData1() {
        //select * from APEX_Customer__c * does not work in SOQL(Salesforce)
        customerId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myid');    
        customerDetails=
            [select id,name,APEX_Active__c,City__c,Country__c,APEX_Customer_Description__c,
             APEX_Customer_Status__c,Email__c,APEX_External_Id__c from APEX_Customer__c 
             where id=:customerId ];
    }

    public PageReference SaveData() {
        string name= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CustomerName');
        System.debug('Name'+name);
        updateCustomer=new List<APEX_Customer__c>();
        for(APEX_Customer__c obj:customerDetails) {
            //obj.name='dhoni';
            obj.name=name;
            updateCustomer.add(obj);
        }

        Update customerDetails;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just want to know when customer change its name then that how to pass that updated value in apex class after clicking on command button.
The below is my page output :[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You can try using inputField instead of inputText in visualforce page. I hope all other fields are getting updated correctly.

Comment: You dont have to pass the user input to the class like you do in Java or .net. In visualforce, they are auto-bound. [This answer by Bob](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008rWDIAY) is simple and well explained and will help you.

Comment: You should remove everything else from your save method, because you don't need any parameter to be passed. You can use only these two lines in your save method, and it would work. **Update customerDetails;
    return null;**

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, It is working now.but I am still confused how it automatically update all the fields which I changed.